# Android: What is a "Bad file number" SocketException?

Tags: java, android, exception

I'm getting a "SocketException: Bad file number" while attempting to read from a socket in an Android app and I have no idea what this means. I've googled it and haven't found any explanation of what it is. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you tried performing a socket operation on something that isn't a socket? Or a socket that has already been closed?

Answer (score 4):

This is usually the result of the underlying socket being closed. The "number" is because file handles in the underlying C code use file numbers to identify handles. The socket may be closed by you, but it may also be closed by security exceptions, flaky network, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have something like this in your code ?

```
       httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

In my case, I had to shutdown my connectionManager **AFTER** getting the response