# SocketException: Bad file number. How can I solve it?

Tags: android

I get a "SocketException: Bad file number" whenever I try to use a `BufferedReader` on a `HttpResponse`. 
Basically I try to parse my response from the server. The strange thing is, that it only happens on my LG 2x (Android 2.2.2), I don't get this error on the Android Emulator (Google 2.2) and on a HTC (2.2).

[In this thread someone explained why the error occurs.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609688/android-what-is-a-bad-file-number-socketexception) But why is the problem only happening on the LG phone, and more importantly, how can I solve it?

```
HttpResponse response = JSONHelper.postJSONObject(WebSMSActivity.this, Consts
                                                .api_url("settings"), json,
                                                "Registration");

// Read the response for the JSON reply
try {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"), 8 * 1024);


    // Read every line (should actually only be
    // one
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String line = null; (line = in.readLine()) != null;) {
        builder.append(line).append("\n");
        Log.w(Consts.LOG_TAG_SERVICE, line);
    }
    String textResponse = builder.toString(); } catch (IOException ex) {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have something like this in your code ?

```
   httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

In my case, I had to shutdown my connectionManager **AFTER** getting the response